# Error "Extra \else" statement with "ceurart"

Tags: pdftex, packages, compilation-error, ifthenelse

I am getting an error when I run pdflatex command on the following .tex document.

```
\documentclass[
% twocolumn,
% hf,
]{ceurart}

\usepackage{minted}

\setminted{breaklines=true}


\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}


\title{A better way to format your document for CEUR-WS}


\maketitle

\section{Introduction}


\end{document}
```

The error is the following:

```
! Extra \else.
\@fileswith@pti@ns ... #3[{#2}][{#4}]#1}\fi \else 
                                                  \def \reserved@b ##1,{\ifx...
l.101 \bool_new:N
                  \g_ceur_pdfx_bool
?
```

How do I resolve this error?

PS: please let me know if what additional information is required for answer this question? Eg log file or something?

Comment: ceurart.cls is not in texlive can you give a link to it?

Comment: I downloaded the template from Overleaf and tried your file. I get an error due to missing data (the conference name), but not the “extra `\else`” error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle does this work? [link](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-XXX/CEURART.zip)

Comment: actually firefox refuses to downloadthat (over http) as a security risk, wget works though

Comment: Using that zip file, I get an error from minted (no way I am running that with `--shell-escape` then an error that `\ceurConference@name ` is not defined  bu no error about `\else` this is with txlive 2022 test relase, what system do you have?